# Why am I not getting No_data_found error when using UPDATE code?

Tags: database, stored-procedures, plsql

I've got the following code, when I use an anonymous block with a id that doesn't exist, the procedures still produce a success output message, not an error message. Why?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPD_CUST_STATUS_IN_DB (pcustid number, pstatus varchar2) IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE CUSTOMER
    SET status = pstatus
    WHERE custid = pcustid;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ORA-20122:ERROR:CUSTOMER ID NOT FOUND');
    WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ORA-20134:ERROR:INVALID STATUS VALUE');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPD_CUST_STATUS_VIASQLDEV (pcustid number, pstatus varchar2) IS 
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('-----------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('Updating Status. Customer Id: ' || pcustid || ' New Status: ' || pstatus);
    UPD_CUST_STATUS_IN_DB(pcustid, pstatus);
    dbms_output.put_line('Update OK');
    commit;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
END;
/
BEGIN
UPD_CUST_STATUS_VIASQLDEV(4, 'SUSPEND');
END;

Actual result: Updating Status. Customer Id: 4 New Status: SUSPEND
Update OK

Expected result: Updating Status. Customer Id: 4 New Status: SUSPEND
ORA-20122:ERROR:CUSTOMER ID NOT FOUND
```

Comment: By the way, you should never use `when others then` without re-raising the exception.

Answer (score 3):

`NO_DATA_FOUND` is an exception that may be raised by a `SELECT` query, if it finds no rows.

You are running an `UPDATE`; if it finds no rows to update no exception will be raised.

If you want to detect that the update found no rows to update, you can use `SQL%ROWCOUNT`, e.g.:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER
SET status = pstatus
WHERE custid = pcustid;

if sql%rowcount=0 then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ORA-20122:ERROR:CUSTOMER ID NOT FOUND');
end if;
```

Answer (score 2):

To test if update successful you can use

```
if sql%found
```

or

```
if sql%notfound
```

instead of

```
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
```

See [PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/13_elems48.htm)